# Create a dir with remote SSH, through python script that's waiting for password

Tags: python, ssh, command-line, subprocess

I have the following command:

"ssh user@ip "mkdir dir/to/were/to/create/a/dir"

in the command line- after entering the above command - it asks for a password, and after entering the password the command works perfectly,
the thing is, that I want to run this command using python script, I thought about subprocess, but I can't get it to enter automatically the password. I don't want to enter it myself, I want the script to do so.

How could I do it?

I also want to run the command scp /path/to/file user@ip:path/to/target/folder/that was/created
(I didn't manage to move the whole folder through SSH which is why I'll do it one by one)
I guess that once I know how to automatically enter the password- I could use it for this command too.

Thank you.

Comment: [`pexpect`](https://pypi.org/project/pexpect/)

Comment: One way is to create a public/private key pair without a password.  Put the public key in the destination machine's `.ssh/authorized_keys` and pass the private key on the ssh command line.

Answer (score 0):

To *literally* answer your question,
you want to `import` [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable).

But really, if you're automating something,
you should arrange for ssh to authenticate
without a password prompt.
Roll a new key with
[ssh-keygen](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-keygen),
add it to the far side's `.ssh/authorized_keys` file,
verify with a quick interactive test,
and you're done.
Or use your current credentials with `ssh-agent` if you prefer.

---

You asked about `ssh` & `scp`,
but of course they authenticate in the same way,
so solving one solves the other.

Over a WAN, roundtrip times can be expensive,
so accomplishing a file transfer via a single
session rather than several can be a win.
Some folks use `$ scp --recursive`.
Here are two techniques that I often use:

1. `$ rsync -av some_dir host:/dest/`
2. `$ tar zcf - some_dir | ssh host 'cd /dest && tar zxvf -'`

Using `rsync` has numerous advantages,
such as avoiding a useless re-copy of a file that's already there.
The second form is more verbose,
but has the advantage of allowing additional commands,
perhaps a `mkdir` or a `make`, as part of setup for the untar.

In each case we preserve timestamps at the destination,
similar to `scp -p`. YMMV, sometimes the time-of-copy
is actually of interest.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware, one could `tar -C /dest` on the far side. I was trying to illustrate how multiple commands may consume a compressed tarchive input stream.

Comment: Thank you very much! @J_H
The thing is that I need to do it on a lot of hosts, so I need to check what will be the best way. I check all what you said:)